# Get id value with PHP Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping

I have this scenario:

```html
<div class="listing_title">
    <strong>
      <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/dectails23291.html" id="url_id_1977">
       Listing Title
      </a>
   </strong>
</div>
```

To get Listing Title, I have implemented this code:

```php
$page = "http://www.mywebsite.com/listings.html";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($pagina);

foreach($html->find('.listing_title') as $element)
    echo $element->first_child()->plaintext  . '<br>';
```

OUTPUT IS:

```
Listing Title
```

Now I need get id value

`url_id_1977`

preferably only "1977", clean of "url_id_", but I dont know do. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: not work in foreach loop, I get this error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: I need get id value end print in same foreach, with this OUTPUT:
Listing Title
1977

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this inside of your `foreach` loop:

`echo end(explode('_', $element->find('a', 0)->id));`

To get rid of the warning you could assign the `id` to a variable:

```
$id = explode('_', $element->find('a', 0)->id);
echo $id[2];
```

Or, if your anchor's `id` always starts with `url_id_`, just use `str_replace()`:

```
echo str_replace('url_id_', '', $element->find('a', 0)->id);
```

Comment: selector working very good! only problem about end and explode, because I get this error: Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference. however your code (about selector) is great!

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

foreach($html->find('*[class=listing_title] a') as $element)
    echo $element->id. '<br>';
```

Comment: with this code I get in output only Listing Title, not id value

Comment: sorry try like this foreach($html->find('*[class=listing_title]') as $element)
    echo  $element->id. '<br>';

Comment: sorry i missed "a" try this foreach($html->find('*[class=listing_title] a') as $element)
        echo $element->id. '<br>';